# Silverlight 4 PLINQ

Tags: .net, silverlight, plinq

I have a very simple question.  Is it possible to use PLINQ with Silverlight 4 since it seems that it doesn't exist in the most commonly referenced assemblies?

Answer (score 2):

It is not supported but you can vote for it here:

http://dotnet.uservoice.com/forums/4325-silverlight-feature-suggestions/suggestions/310712-plinq-and-tpl?ref=title

Comment: I just want to know if I can use it or not.  That's all.

Answer (score 2):

http://portabletpl.codeplex.com/

PortableTPL is a portable project inspired by the Task Parallel Library. It can be used with .Net 4.0, Silverlight 4.0, XNA 4.0 for XBox 360 and Silverlight for Windows Phone. PortableTPL supports following features:

- Task
- Task
- Task Continuation
- Task Cancelleation with CancellationTokenSource
- AggregationException
- Parallel.For
- Parallel.ForEach
- Schedulers

Answer (score 0):

Not at this time. Neither the Task parallel library or PLINQ have been implemented in Silverlight yet. At the rate the Silverlight team is cranking out releases though... who knows!