# AsParallel not available in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight

I want to traverse all the children in some container (Grid, Canvas etc) in parallel way. I am not able to find AsParallel() even though i have reference to `System.Linq`. What should i do as a workaround for this to take advantage of full CPU power of client?

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Will AsParallel help? If you're doing any work on the children (setting properties etc.), they'll still have to be serialised onto the UI thread.

Comment: Duplicate question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718347/silverlight-4-plinq

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that Parallel extensions didnt make it into SL 4.0

However rewriting function like Parallel.For shouldnt be too hard. You can find required code here in a great Joe Duffys article

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163427.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A NuGet package has been available in this area,

http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks/

which uses Mono's source code and compiles for Silverlight/Windows Phone/.NET 3.5.